# Ubuntu 14.04 Server should block specific websites over OpenVPN

Tags: 14.04, vpn, openvpn

I am running an Ubuntu 14.04 server to host an OpenVPN server on it.
Now I need to block some websites/IPs to prevent abuse over the OpenVPN server.
Is there a 'good' way (without using the hosts file) to block these websites or IPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You do it the same way you block websites for users on your company
>   network: Run a proxy server and force everyone's web traffic through
>   it.

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/518374/website-filtering-for-openvpn-clients